# android load an image from gallery with int ID?

Tags: android, android-image

hi I'm trying to load an image into a custom class, this class currently uses an int ID of an internal resource image, but I want the option to use gallery or photo images as well.

this is the current piece of code which creates the view with an internal resource image.

```
 public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int pic) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        Log.i(TAG, "pic before: "+pic);
        if (pic ==0) pic = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher" , "drawable", "com.example.testimage");
        Log.i(TAG, "pic afgter: "+pic);
        //mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.testpic);
        mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(pic);

        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

        mDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(context, new GestureCallback());
    }
```

You can see above the code is using "pic" to allow the internal resource ID to be passed through. however I'd like to use the ID brought from the mediastore as shown here:

```
final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
                Cursor imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);
                if(imageCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    int id = imageCursor.getInt(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID));
                    TouchExampleView view = new TouchExampleView(this, null, 0, id);
                    }
```

unfortunately its not working.

Comment: what is the value of id that u r getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make another `constructor` with a `drawable`

Like

```
 public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, Drawable pic) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Log.i(TAG, "pic before: "+pic);
    if (pic == null) pic = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Log.i(TAG, "pic afgter: "+pic);
    //mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.testpic);
    mIcon = pic;

    mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

    mDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(context, new GestureCallback());
}
```

and get drawable like this

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    File file = new File(filePath);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
```

now create a new object of `TouchExampleView` with the `Drawable`

```
new TouchExampleView(context, attrs, defStyle, d)
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thats great, it does work for me. And it shows I still have much to learn on Java! Would you mind taking a look at my other outstanding question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/16427699/828395), as this particular question came about with me trying a workaround for the real issue. cheers.